# How to keep separation of concerns in ASP.NET Boilerplate template and use spatial information query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using [ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/) in the "Core" library I have this class:

```
public class Post : Entity<Guid>
{
    public Post()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Hashtags = new HashSet<Hashtag>();
    }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hashtag> Hashtags { get; set; }
}
```

I searched and found the Entity Framework can handle spatial data query better using [DbGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.spatial.dbgeography(v=vs.113).aspx) class. The problem is I don't want to use Entity Framework in the Core library ...

Is there any way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way around ?

Short answer: **no**

If you want to use a type defined in the EF-library you need to reference it.

But I see no reason not to reference the EF-library in the core library to use it's types, if it will be loaded by other projects in your application anyhow.
I have about the same scenario here and my entities project references EF just to "have access" to the data annotations, but is not "using" EF in a sense of defining a `DbContext` or executing any initialization or querying and so does not break the separation of concerns.

Comment: Now I had to add EntityFramework to Core and Application Projects ... I feel that it's not the way it should go :\